# Smoke Simulation - Bake Offset before Frame 0

Tags: keyframes, baking, smoke-simulation

Helo, i am wondering how to offset smoke simulation, treat it as if keyframes.

ie. you simulated 250 frames of smoke, you want the animation to start on frame 125

(ex. fluid simulations have "offset" slider )

Answer (score 1):

I am answering myself, it is a workaround

1. set frame Start: -125 frame End: 125
2. click "Bake" the sim should bake, but not move in preview
3. "Free Bake" and go to frame 0
4. Let the smoke simulate in viewport from frame 0(do not click Bake)
5. Click "Current cache to bake"

Voilá

Answer (score 0):

Set the start of the animation to the desired frame. In the timeline tab, there should be a part that says "Start" and "End." Change the "Start" frame after you have finished baking to animate from that point.

Comment: Thanks, but my question was how to shift only the smoke sim back and forth.

Comment: Ah- If you want your sim to start at a certain frame, first save the Blend file and then go to the Smoke Cache tab in the Smoke Domain settings, and set the start and end frame. Does this help?